# Numpy-convertible class that correctly converts to ndarray from inside a sequence?

Tags: numpy

The `__array__` method allows a custom type to automatically convert to numpy.  E.g.,

```
>>> class Convertible:
...  def __array__(self):
...    return np.zeros(7)
>>> np.array(Convertible())
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Unfortunately, `__array__` doesn't work if the custom type occurs inside a sequence:

```
>>> np.array([Convertible(), Convertible()])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Convertible'
```

Is there a way to fix `Convertible` so that converting a sequence of `Convertible` objects to numpy with `np.array` is the same as converting each one and then converting the sequence of resulting `ndarrays`?

Comment: "Fix" it how?  You'll have to specify expected behaviour because there are several choices here.

Comment: Edited the text to explicitly say that I want the natural behavior.

Comment: `np.stack([Convertible(), Convertible()])` should produce a (2,7) array of zeros.

Comment: That's true but it dodges the goal, which is that I want `[Convertible(), Convertible()]` to work as an argument to `__array__`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It'd have to be a sequence.

`numpy.array` [takes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)

> An array, any object exposing the array interface, an object whose `__array__` method returns an array, or any (nested) sequence.

When you call `numpy.array` on a `Convertible` instance, you're hitting the "an object whose `__array__` method returns an array" case. When you call it on a list of Convertibles, you're hitting the "any (nested) sequence" case. The type inference logic appears to be picking up the `__array__` method you defined when determining the dtype of the new array, but after that, since your objects don't provide the sequence protocol, NumPy assumes your objects should be converted to ints directly.

Implement `__len__` and `__getitem__`, and you should be able to convert `[Convertible(), Convertible()]` to an array. NumPy is going to *use* the sequence protocol instead of `__array__` when you do that, though, which is going to involve more Python method calls than you probably wanted. You'd have to do something other than a direct `numpy.array` call if you want to prevent that.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it :) However, it looks like you also need to define the `__iter__' method. At least for me the code otherwise appears to hang.

Comment: @ThomasKühn: That's because your `__getitem__` has a bug; it's not raising `IndexError` for invalid indices.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Learned something new again -- will fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your object also has to be iterable. The following code,

```
import numpy as np

class Convertible:
    def __array__(self):
        return np.zeros(7)

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(7):
            yield 0    

    def __len__(self):
        return 7

    def __getitem__(self, n):
        if n > 6:
            raise IndexError('index out of range')
        return 0


print(np.array(Convertible()))
print()
print(list(Convertible()))
print()
print(np.asarray((Convertible(),Convertible())))
```

works for me:

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```